# Term For Rotating 3d Vectors About a Pivot Point

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, computational-geometry

What is the term for Rotating a 3d Vector about another 3d Vector (Pivot Point)?

For example; if I want to move X distance from one point towards another point - the mathematical term for this operation is called `Linear Interpolation` (or `Lerp` in the computer graphics world).

What would be the mathematical term/formula/function for rotating a 3d Vector about another 3d Vector (Pivot Point)?

The reason I need to know if because I have a C# Math Library and I need to rotate some 3d Vectors using this library. I dont know the mathematical term for this, so I dont know which Programming Class or Method I should use.

Answer (score 1):

Rotating a vector about a point (vector) other than the origin is an example of an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

Even if there is no method whereby you can "rotate one vector around another" directly, doing this "from scratch" should be easy enough in any environment that supports basic matrix manipulations.

Hopefully that helps you with your search.